# Laravel 7 filters

Tags: php, laravel

I have successfully created a logging and registration system!

I get to the part where I need to do the sign out option.

My course I bought at **Udemy** is a bit old so I don't have a file called **filters.php**

I searched on the internet to find a file called **filters.php** and found one post saying **Middleware** was used instead of **filter.php**

How to create a **Sign out option** now using **Middleware**?

---

Web.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()){

}
```

Comment: How you create your login and registration feature? using the Laravel Authentication feature shown as https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the sign out option, which it already included in **Laravel Authentication**.

You can get more information about how to setup it at the link below:-

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Otherwise, **Laravel Authentication** almost cover all authentication functions such as login, reset password and logout.

When you complete the setup. It will generate the middleware and controller for the Authentication feature. You just need to add some code at your route file.

```
Auth::routes(); //This line help to declare the route used by Laravel Authentication

Route::group(['middleware'=>['admin']],function(){

//Declare Your Route that only allowed access by the logged in user here

});
```