# Auth user showing Null in outside of auth api passport

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an app where I am fetching user details with Laravel passport API get method with query string.
But when I put that route in auth API it shows "route login not found" and when I put outside auth API it shows Null when I call `Auth::user()`.

Here is my route and my API with method:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');

Route::get('GetUserClaims', 'AuthController@GetUserClaims');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
//Route::get('details', 'AuthController@details');
//Route::get('GetUserClaims', 'AuthController@GetUserClaims');
});

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/public/api/GetUserClaims?userKey=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ijg3M2E4NTdhZmViMGVhMzAzNWQ5ZGU5NGZmNTUzMmI4NGUyMDZjZjE0MjRhYzQxZjI0YjUwYjdmZjc4OWZmYjM5YzhmNjBlZjRmYzM0OTQzIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiODczYTg1N2FmZWIwZWEzMDM1ZDlkZTk0ZmY1NTMyYjg0ZTIwNmNmMTQyNGFjNDFmMjRiNTBiN2ZmNzg5ZmZiMzljOGY2MGVmNGZjMzQ5NDMiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODUwODU5NDksIm5iZiI6MTU4NTA4NTk0OSwiZXhwIjoxNjE2NjIxOTQ5LCJzdWIiOiI2Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.VXKRTTpZxMGq4gR8kdu9qREBvhxSfPz4WureEYCpr-nh-qMFqkuR9Q10oa4AotmNmIABRFb_ijyrpt1AVJOpPU4b0R4lEnUWq746wh3etBg37fuSvDx8XDwF84NcOyU1GNnXDZ0KLbwr4YjrOqtuPNBAtkDEPHOKUYdxHvYOUSqt8YIx-L1p2ijHEvYDKroG8-B9mZs97HCtgSpwqTv7b5I0hEV4b1Ifkm24qDhoRMvaSYDFGcu52VWfwPjMEq6NPDYwwBx9Jpv_wv8-UA8BZPqECzE-D7xw46X4IhUNg9PyGxhtWbMvipz1E1OFzb_lBmgYTU5JVx0s0wmmcjqAq4jlfHNarUdBQGziJR4m3rLBGYNtLmqQ4kR1knrhaR-qQYaKiQNknxtb7c_HG724G_XSYkzFJZUalLFtQkDYpXSSP-QgzKFrQHblE6Led2AwPqt4S4svDOht5hqg29TejNbggIztj_fs9u2cwso1VvPjAM1LLG8chzVT5PM6YTihDGaVf4VEUaQmClgG64pEq2TmJISTLsplqlG1wn2BTdmCcO69VZYBvLJvjDlm942RGAYaNHD7Wt3RbJxMOH3RF8OGRP_H2IvIwtWz4x29dDUg8fMEKlA-nM1A8wsrK-YFkbwrY-IOzHl-4MdPopmXiFViB5RPMkQdCMd0ItWTjgA

public function GetUserClaims(Request $request) 
{ 
  if ( $request->has('userKey') ){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $request->userKey;
    var_dump($user);
    //$token='Bearer '.$request->bearerToken();
    //$request->header('Authorization',$token);

    //return response()->json(['user' => auth()->user()], 200);
    //return response()->json(['success' => $user], Response::HTTP_OK);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to the solution below to solved you issue.

> [Laravel 7 filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805647/laravel-7-filters/60807078#60807078)

The guide lead you about how to setup `Laravel Authentication` which include at `Laravel` package.

You don't have to build out from scratch by yourself

Comment: if i declare inside auth api then it shows route login not fount and if i add auth::routes to api routes then it shows authlogin view not found in postman..but i dont need view

Comment: You need to run "php artisan make:auth" at cmd for setup the Laravel Authentication

Comment: i did ..but only login view is running in postman if in inside auth api ..unable to fetch user info in both outside auth api and inside auth api..

Comment: For your information, you can't use the any authentication feature by session at postman. because the API request from postman doesn't using cookie, so your session is not detectable via postman.

Comment: If you want develop the User Authentication for your Rest API. you required to use another package called "laravel/passport". You can learn more here https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: You can add following handler to solved "route login not found" issue. More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43254688/3912414